# RadioButton back to false after adding new RadioButton

Tags: c#, xaml, radio-button

i have one `for` loop that create 3 RadioButton with `IsChecked` Property true.

I'm  adding the RadioButton to StackPanel in ui.When it completed adding radiobuttons i see only the last radiobutton added in page have IsChecked Property to true everyone else has false.

so when layout updates with new radiobutton added all others radiobutton in the stackpanel are set to false here is the code

```
for(var l = 0 ; l< 3 ; l++){
   RadioButton radiobutton = new RadioButton();
   radiobutton.IsChecked = true;
   stackpanel.children.add(radiobutton);
}
```

Comment: I need to see your full code (for the list, at least). How are you adding the list? Is there a `page_load()` in between?

Comment: Well, that is the very nature of radiobuttons: only __one in a group__ of them is checked.

Comment: sorry i wasn't very clear , i have two stackpanel so in every stackpanel i added three RadioButtons button only the last radioButton of last stackpanel is checked

Comment: @GranitBerisha Can you show an example of this behaviour in action?

Answer (score 2):

As TaW already commented, with radiobuttons only one can be checked. If you want multiple checks I suggest you use checkboxes.